# Знамени - способ образования слова?

Tags: словообразование

Знамени - это суффиксальный способ образования слова или просто форма родительного падежа?

Покачивал - это суффиксальный способ или опять же форма одного и того же слова, просто поменяли вид?

Answer (score 9):

При образовании нового слова меняется лексическое значение. Суффикс -ЕН- у разносклоняемых существительных образует не новое слово, а формы косвенных падежей. 
Глаголы разных видов считаются разными словами. Вид - постоянный признак глагола. Подкачать и подкачивать - разные слова.

Answer (score 0):

Слово "покачивал" - образовалось суффиксальным способом от н.ф. "подкачивать"

Answer (score 0):

Насчет знамени - согласен, никак не отдельное слово, а вот пламя и пламень благополучно сосуществуют как разные слова, хотя имеют общие формы косвенных падежей. И в этом случае без специальной оговорки трудно было бы сказать, что имеется в виду...